# Track a user's location even when they aren't using it and constantly update it into Firebase

Tags: swift, swift3, core-location

I'm trying to set up a system where users with a certain account type will always have their location tracked, even when it is terminated and isn't in use. I also want to constantly update that location (in longitude and latitude) into firebase whenever any change in location occurs. I've read about needing to use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges however I can't seem to figure out how to use this and it only seems to from what I've read to update it only if a location change of over 1km has occurred.

### Edit

Ankit's answers works well, but I'm still confused about how would I go about updating the user's location when the app is terminated into my database through the app delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, you must enable background mode in the

```
Xcode Project > Capabilities pane.
```

If you want updates even when your app is terminated, you must use ***startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges*** to get location updates.

```
Limits: Event will fire when device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification.
```

**Tradeoff:**

Normally use: `startUpdatingLocation()` for frequent events
but in  `applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)`
modify that locationObject and call its `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`

Use below method:

```
func startBackgroundLocationUpdates() {
    // Create a location manager object
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    // Request location authorization
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers

    // Enable automatic pausing
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

    // Specify the type of activity your app is currently performing
    locationManager.activityType = .fitness

    // Enable background location updates, after iOS 9 its must
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

    // Start location updates in terminated mode as well
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    //or for frequents events
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Now location updates are delivered to your delegate’s locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) method.

If your app is terminated, the system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new event arrives. with options dictionary passed to *application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)* methods of your app delegate contains the key location to indicate that your app was launched because of a location event.

Now since your app has been launched in background , you can implement your logic here to send updates to server but do remember following thing:

**Upon relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call this method *`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`* to continue receiving location events.**

*Also remember to call the stopUpdatingLocation method of the location manager object when location updates are no longer needed*

Comment: Ok so just clarifying when the app is terminated, I will have to send the updates to my database from my app delegate? EDIT: Also how would I be able to go about testing this within the simulator? Because when I terminate the app, monitoring of the console and other stuff stops working.

Comment: this can't be tested on simulator. You have to use actual device for that.

Comment: According to me, for viewing that your app has been launched via location update, you should save such counts in UserDefaults whenever application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) contains location key so that when you connect back, you will know that your app was launched based on that defaults value.

Comment: Ok I understand that, but how would I go about updating the user's location when the app is terminated into my database and implementing code to do those things above?

Comment: since you have control in application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) , via location key, you can implement your logic there.